# How would I convert my discord.py discord bots code that I use to get a list of members in a voice channel to the new discord.py version?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command that creates of list of members in a specific voice channel. For example !attendance general for the "general" voice channel. My issue is that some of the parts no longer work since i was using an older version of discord.py.I recently ran the cmd line to upgrade discord.py and it seems a bunch of commands are now different.

My question is how do I get a specific channel and find its member list now? Below is my old code that no longer works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRK72.png

The part of code thats causing trouble is in the link. basically it loops through all voice channels for a specific one named general, then goes through each user in voice and checks if they have the tag "guest". If they do it adds to a list.

It seems that im not able to get a list of channels or loop through the members using ch.voice_members anymore, does anyone know the new formatting/commands for these issues?

Im summary I need to find commands for being able to check if a channel matches and then a way to loop through all the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the discord.py docs - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

looks like you can change

```
for user in ch.voice_members
```

to

```
for user in ch.members
```

Looks like there are no longer separate properties for member lists